# NetworkManager: where is the specification for its DBus interface?

Tags: linux

where is the specification for Network Manager's DBus interface?

I've been googling like crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NetworkManagerDBusInterface - GNOME Live!](http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManagerDBusInterface)

> The API documentation is written in an XML format, and is available here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/introspection
>
> You can transform it into HTML with these steps:
>
> - checking out NM from SVN, http://www.gnome.org/projects/NetworkManager/developers/
> - configure --with-docs
> - (obsolete: change terminate=yes to terminate=no in tools/doc-generator.xsl)
> - make docs/spec.html

Comment: ... I have used D-feet on the System Bus also to try to make sense of the doc.